# JQuery mobile dynamic popup and arrows

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to show a popup after I have changed its contents.

Here's my markup:

```
<div id="welcome" data-role="page" class="js" data-theme="a">
    <header data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="a">
        <a href="#prop-popup" data-role="button" data-rel="popup" >Popup</a>
        <a id="btn" href="#" data-role="button" data-rel="popup" >Popup2</a>
        <h1>Page title</h1>
    </header>
    <div id="welcome-main" role="main" class="ui-content">
        Page content
    </div>
    <div id="prop-popup" data-role="popup" data-inset="true" data-theme="a" data-arrow="t">
        Popup content
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's my JavaScript:

```
$(document).on("click", "#btn", function(e) {
    $("#prop-popup").html("Blablabla");
    $("#prop-popup").popup("open", {
        arrow: "t",
        positionTo: "#btn"
    });
});
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/robbyn/oLde37dg/

Now the first (left) button will correctly show the popup, with an arrow on the top. But if I try to alter the content of the popup before it's shown, as it is the case with the second (right) button, the arrow will not show.

How can I fix that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: jQuery adds some code to your popup. You are overwiting this code using the `.html` method, that's why you loose you arrow. I currently can't check on it but the content of the popup you want to edit is in some child element of your `#prop-popup`. Just to try `$('#prop-popup > *:eq(0).html('bla')` for now..

Comment: I really meant `$('#prop-popup > *:eq(1)').html('bla')`

Answer (score 0):

I've found one answer: destroy and recreate the popup:

```
$("#prop-popup").popup("destroy");
$("#prop-popup").html("Blablabla");
$("#prop-popup").popup().popup("open", {
    arrow: "t",
    positionTo: "#btn"
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oLde37dg/1/

Comment: Thats not necessary, just use the `html` method on the right child of your popup, as I mentioned above!

Comment: Yes, thanks for your comment, but I prefer not to rely on undocumented features.

Comment: @MauricePerry, rico's solution is better that destroying and reinitializing the widget each time you show it: https://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/oLde37dg/4/

Comment: @ezanker thanks. I prefer not to rely on undocumented features.